# jQuery Ajax POST call with JSON in Rest Web Service Issue

Tags: ajax, json, post, jersey, jax-rs

I want to post a JSON object from my page to a Rest WS. But when I am posting json through jQuery ajax call as output I am getting a HTML page with "**HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed**" instate of JSON, which I am sending from Rest Web Service. Please refer the following code snippet.

I am using jquery 1.11.3 version.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

jQuery Ajax Call:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/api/myService/jsonpost",
        method: "POST",
        data: jsonObj,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(result){
              alert(result);
         },
         error(){
             console.log('Error');
         }
    });
```

Please note my rest web service is running in my local tomcat.

Please find my Rest Web Service POST code.

```
@POST
@Path("/jsonpost")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String crunchifyJsonPostREST(SampleVO input) throws JSONException{
    SampleVO sampleVO = input;
    return new Gson().toJson(sampleVO);
}
```

VO:

```
public class SampleVO {

private String name;

/**
 * @return the name
 */

@XmlElement
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

**My Maven Dependency is:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Firebug Details:**

Please find my ajax request Header.

[image]

Please find my ajax response and response HTML.
 [image]
[image]

Need your help to resolve this issue.

Thanks is advance.

**Solution:**

After lot of googling I have found some solution. Now I am using HTTP-Proxy-Servlet.

I have crated a java web application with my html page which has the ajax call and from my ajax call I am calling a URL of same domain. Please refer my ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "rest/api/crunchifyService/jsonpost",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(result,status,jqXHR ){
              //Do something
         },
         error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             //Do something
         }
    });
```

Now I have done this same domain call mapping with org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet. Please refer my web xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
        <param-value><!-- Cross domain URL goes here --></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now my ajax is calling this Proxy Servlet and it is redirecting to the CROS destination Rest Web Service.

Please refer the following URL, you will get more details.

https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

Comment: Are you sure that `http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/api/myService/jsonpost` is accessible using a POST request? It seems that it's not.

Comment: @DavidePastore , how you are saying that the URL is not accessible using POST request? One thing I would like to mention that when I am calling the URL using Ajax there is no hit to my web service server.

Comment: Do you have other resources that you serve from your web application (using Jersey)?

Comment: @DavidePastore GET is working fine. Issue with the POST only.

Comment: Is your GET in the same class of the POST?

Comment: @DavidePastore, yes. The GET in the same class of POST

Comment: Can you add your AJAX code?

Comment: @DavidePastore , Ajax code is already added in the top of description section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of googling I have found some solution. Now I am using HTTP-Proxy-Servlet.

I have crated a java web application with my html page which has the ajax call and from my ajax call I am calling a URL of same domain. Please refer my ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "rest/api/crunchifyService/jsonpost",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(result,status,jqXHR ){
              //Do something
         },
         error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             //Do something
         }
    });
```

Now I have done this same domain call mapping with org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet. Please refer my web xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
        <param-value><!-- Cross domain URL goes here --></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now my ajax is calling this Proxy Servlet and it is redirecting to the CROS destination Rest Web Service.

Please refer the following URL, you will get more details.

https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

Answer (score 1):

datatype should be `dataType: 'json'`

If you are using `contentType: "application/json",` , then you should stringify your data.

```
data:JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
```

Comment: Tried this solution, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using type & contentType settings of ajax:

```
type:'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Example:

```
function loadDoc(){
  var num = '{"empid": 45,"name": "gaurav","salary":566.55}';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:9029/addS',
    method: 'POST',
    type:'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response){
      console.log("response::::"+response);
      $("#output").text(response);
    },
    error: function( jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log("Error askdjk");
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });   
}
```